# Retrieve parameter from JSTL part in form

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have in a form in an JSP following code:

```
Feedbackverantwoordelijke : 
<select name="feedbackverantwoordelijken">
    <c:forEach items="${feedbackverantwoordelijken}" var="feedbackverantwoordelijke">
        <option value="$(feedbackverantwoordelijke.id}">
        <c:out value="${feedbackverantwoordelijke.userName}" />
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select><br>
```

How to I retrieve the parameter from this list?

if I use : `request.getParameter("feedbackverantwoordelijke")` I get an HTTP STATUS **405** – HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL??? (no reason why)

if I use : `request.getParameter("feedbackverantwoordelijken")` I get String : `$(feedbackverantwoordelijke.id}`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error message means your servlet doesn't have `doPost()` overridden.

See the [doPost](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) docs.

And take a look your code carefully, should

```
<option value="$(feedbackverantwoordelijke.id}">
be              |
                |
<option value="${feedbackverantwoordelijke.id}">
```

?

Comment: Agreed.  But the servlet do has an doPost method and when I change the parameter I don't get an error.  But the main question is what is the correct parameter to retrieve the value of the list.

Comment: Damn, missed that one!  Should have seen it because of the string I got in return.  Thx al lot!!